# Pandas 'function' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm unable to get the 'to_excel' method to function correctly.

My code is as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

file = 'PistonPrices.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=0)

df = df[df.price != 'POA']
df = df[df.price != 'AUCTION']
df = df.drop_duplicates

df.to_excel('PistonClean.xlsx')
```

I get the error:

```sh
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

Comment: You forget `()` - `df = df.drop_duplicates()`

Comment: Ah yes, of course. thanks both. that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is incorrect `df = df.drop_duplicates` instead of assigning the return value of a function `drop_duplicates` you are assigning a function so now `df` points to `drop_duplicates` and this function do not poses methods they are callable and that is it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your line just before your df.to_excel. Look up the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) if you want to put specific options. But since it is a function you have to at least put ()

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates
```

You're assigning the `drop_duplicates` function to the `df` variable. You probably forgot the `()` at the end of `drop_duplicates`.

The function `drop_duplicates` does not have an extension function called `to_excel`, so the error is correct.

If you change

```
df = df.drop_duplicates
```

to

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

you will see that your code runs. This is because df.drop_duplicates() returns a DataFrame, and a DataFrame has the `to_excel()` function.